# No result when reading an image for Handwritten Recognition using tesseract

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

Currently I'm trying to implement a handwritten recognition program that will identify A,B,C,D, & E and numbers from 1-100. what I tried so far is using PyTesseract. I had made a simple pytesseract code with this one

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
src_path = "test-img/"

def get_string(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)

    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "sample.jpg", img)

    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "thres.png", img)

    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres.png"))

    return result

print(get_string(src_path + "n.jpg") )
```

However, whenever I tried running the program. I don't get any result at all.

[image]

Can Someone help me with this one. Is there any alternative and easier way to implement handwritten recognition using python? Thank you

Sample image to detect
[image]

Comment: Can you attach sample input images ?

Comment: @ZdaR edited. Kindly check it

Comment: Tesseract is generally used to detect printed characters and is less suitable for hand written characters. There are some other projects which handle this gracefully: [blog1](https://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/), [Github](https://github.com/topics/mnist-handwriting-recognition?l=python), [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer)

Comment: Okay I will try this one. Thank you for the help

Comment: @ZdaR how can I add a new dataset to train in keras? to detect A-E Letters?

Comment: An SO answer may not suffice your needs, you may need to look up some MOOCs, I don't think there would be any shortcut for this.

Comment: Thus this one takes time when training?

Comment: Yes training your custom model has it's own machine and time requirements